# Set and get custom attributes on input fields in html

Tags: jquery, html

I have to set a custom attribute to each input field. My inputs are below. Am I able to set attributes like this?

```
<input typeid='1' type='checkbox' class='chk' id='inp1' />
<input typeid='1' type='checkbox' class='chk' id='inp1' />
<input typeid='1' type='checkbox' class='chk' id='inp1' />
<input typeid='2' type='checkbox' class='chk' id='inp1' />
<input typeid='2' type='checkbox' class='chk' id='inp1' />
<input typeid='3' type='checkbox' class='chk' id='inp1' />
```

Here, typeid is my custom attribute. Now I want to access the inputs that have typeid =1. How do I do this?

Comment: **1.** Use `$('input[typeid="1"]')`. **2.** To add custom attributes, use HTML5 `data-*` attribute. **3.** ID should be **unique**

Answer (score 5):

Try like this:

```
<input data-typeid='1' type='checkbox' class='chk' id='inp1' />
```

and javascript to set and get

```
$("#inp1").data('typeid', 2); // to set value
var value = $("#inp1").data('typeid'); //to get value
```